# How to get download time, when download file using anchor tag <a>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, ecmascript-6

there is no callBack, so i don't know, how to get download time

if there have some other way, like: get net speed and file size, use size / speed ? or other method.

thank you

Comment: look for http://usefulangle.com/post/68/javascript-ajax-download-file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with an  tag. If you want to get a file use AJAX with JavaScript:

http://usefulangle.com/post/68/javascript-ajax-download-file

With this you will be able to get progress, file size, etc.